# Scala Lift Tomcat 6 - Define webroot

Tags: scala, tomcat, lift

I'm attempting to deploy my webapp to tomcat but am having some issues with an upload path.

When uploading files they end up in the Tomcat root, as apposed to the webapp root.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to provide some meaningful information about what you've actually tried, rather than making people guess.